# Can't figure out why it matches a condition

Tags: python

```
if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    f = sys.argv[1]
elif len(sys.argv) == 3 and ('--full' in sys.argv or '--last' in sys.argv):
    f = sys.argv[2]
else:
    print "Error!!\n\n"
    show_info()
    sys.exit()

if '--full' in sys.argv:
    #code
elif '--last' in sys.argv:
    #code
elif '--help' or '-h' in sys.argv:
    show_info()
    sys.exit()
```

show_info() is just some prints showing a description and how to use the script.

If I run for instance `python test.py my_file` it enters the last `elif`, but neither `--help` nor `-h` is in `sys.argv`... Why is this happening?

Comment: `'--help' or '-h' in sys.argv` should be `'--help' in sys.argv or '-h' in sys.argv`

Comment: lol what a mistake xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing an `in sys.argv`:

```
elif '--help' in sys.argv or '-h' in sys.argv:
```

`elif '--help'` is always going to evaluate to True as will any non empty string.

Comment: No worries, easy mistake to make.